# robot_localization - gps and imu minimal example not working

Tags: navigation, gps, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some trouble getting `robot_localization` working. I have tried several configurations but nothing gives me a good result. So I thought I would try to get the minimal working. I have gps data and imu data. I also have wheel odometry. All this is simulated and all the values are currently almost ideal (no or very small noise). I use navsat with the following conf:

```
navsat_transform:
  frequency: 30
  delay: 3.0
  magnetic_declination_radians: 0 # 
  yaw_offset: 0
  zero_altitude: true
  broadcast_utm_transform: true
  publish_filtered_gps: true
  use_odometry_yaw: true
  wait_for_datum: false
```

And then I use one ekf node with the following conf:

```
  odom0: odom
  odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true, true, true,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom0_queue_size: 10
  odom0_nodelay: true
  odom0_differential: false
  odom0_relative: false

  odom1: odometry/gps
  odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                 false, false, false,
                 true, true, true,
                 false, false, false,
                 false, false, false]
  odom1_queue_size: 10
  odom1_nodelay: true
  odom1_differential: false
  odom1_relative: false

  imu0: imu/data
  imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  false,
                true,  true,  true]
  imu0_nodelay: false
  imu0_differential: false
  imu0_relative: false
  imu0_queue_size: 10
  imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

The conf is pretty taken from the examples.

I have static transform for `map` -> `odom` (they are exactly the same). ekf publishes `odom` -> `base_link` transform. The latitude-longitude are exactly aligned with y and x axis.

Wheel odometry is in odom topic.

**The problem I am facing**: when there is no movement, the filtered odometry (also the transform from `odom` to `base_link`) starts moving slowly (the robot itself is not moving). When the robot is moving, everything gets messy pretty quickly.

I have tried to exclude imu, odom, change covariance, all the other parameters. What is my problem here? I would like to get a minimal example working, which would mainly use GPS.

EDIT:

To be exact, the movement of the transform grows strangely. Here are some example of my tf topic (two consecutive messages, we use base_footprint instead of base_link):

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 7
    nsecs: 200000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.00408947608922
    y: -0.0837722308319
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.241644993047
    w: 0.970364723872

    
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 7
    nsecs: 250000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.215371691561
    y: -0.862578741381
    z: 0.0
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: -0.574137811256
    w: 0.818758678541
```

And after that it goes wild. The strange thing here is that the rotation also changes. Although imu sensor simulator should be pretty stable. And every time I run the simulator, it gets about the same results (about the same time).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269631/robot_localization---gps-and-imu-minimal-example-not-working/) by [Ago](https://answers.ros.org/users/31489/ago/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-10-03**:
Please provide sample input messages. Also, is there a reason you are fusing velocities from `/odometry/gps`, or is that a remnant from the examples?

**Comment by [Ago](https://answers.ros.org/users/31489/ago/) on 2017-10-23**:
Thanks for the reply! Yes, gps odom comes from the examples. Comes out imu simulator was very wrong. Now I have managed to get IMU simulator working, everything seems to work just fine. But I will open a new question regarding the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My main problem was very noisy (I would even say random) IMU simulator (due to physics and model in gazebo). After fixing this, the localization is spot on!

---

Originally posted by [Ago](https://answers.ros.org/users/31489/ago/) with karma: 23 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0